# How can I install the daily build of the ubuntu kernel into the ubuntu live CD?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, live-usb

I don't have a clear idea of how to put into the live CD the newest kernel build(4.7 at this time)

I tried downloading the kernel from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/

How can I put the latest version of the kernel into the ubuntu 16.04 live CD?

Comment: Do you want to boot into the new kernel image? If that's the case, then you'll actually need to re-create the Live CD with it.

Comment: Yes I would like to boot into the new kernel 4.7 image, @thiagowfx do you know any "easy" way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but it's not that easy. I think there might be easier ways, you can try to search for "Ubuntu generate live image". See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) can be a good starting point. You'll likely need an already existing Linux running, will download Ubuntu sources, prepare the system with anything you want (kernel, in your case) and then create an image out of it.